# React Native - TypeError: this.addItem.bind

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bind

I am trying to learn React and make a Todo List.

I got this error :

> TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evalauting 'this.addItem.bind')

I think the error is about 'addItem' function but I could not find the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

This is the code:

```
import MyButton from './button';

  const listItems = ["Ödevini Yap","İşe Git"];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    toDo: '',
  }

  AddItem() {
    console.warn('App::addItem', this.state.toDo);
    this.setState({ toDo: '' })
  }

  renderItem(item) {
    return(
      <View>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <TextInput value = { this.state.toDo } onChangeText = {(v) => this.setState({ toDo: v }) } placeholder = 'Enter ToDo Item'></TextInput>
          </View>
          <View>
            <MyButton onPress = {this.AddItem} text = {'Ekle'}></MyButton>
          </View>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          {
            listItems.map( (item) => this.renderItem(item) )
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change AddItem to addItem

Comment: Thanks this helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
```

to

```
this.addItem = this.AddItem.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo

```
this.AddItem = this.AddItem.bind(this); //fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

You made typo error

Change

```
AddItem() {
    console.warn('App::addItem', this.state.toDo);
    this.setState({ toDo: '' })
  }
```

To

```
addItem() {
    console.warn('App::addItem', this.state.toDo);
    this.setState({ toDo: '' })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me.